# Allow access after sharing url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, twitter

On a MVC 5 web site I would like visitors to be able to read the full version of a post only after they shared it on Facebook or Twitter.

I have seen this example in a few web sites ... What would be the best way to do this?

There is no real security issues here ... It is just a way to spread the word ...

My first idea would be to save a cookie with a post KEY (Guid) ... This key is not visible to the user so he will not know the value.

The problem is how do I know that he shared the url ... How do I get the confirmation?

Thank You,

Miguel

Answer (score 0):

You get confirmation as follows, per the [Facebook Developers Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/):

```
FB.ui(
{
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
},
function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was shared.'); //give access to article
    } else {
      alert('Post was not shared.'); //they chose not share... don't give access
    }
});
```

I implemented this code almost verbatim in a .NET project (just replaced the `alerts` with my own functionality) where I gave users two entries into a contest if they shared the contest page (instead of one entry if they didn't share or did nothing).

As for Twitter, I've personally not implemented something similar, but your best bet is probably [JavaScript Interfaces for Twitter for Websites](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Facebook, but with Twitter a retweet is the same as a share. The statuses/retweeters/ids should work. If you have the id of the tweet, then you can hold a list of who retweeted it, updating as needed to get new ids.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweeters/ids

If you don't want to write all of the code to authenticate and configure the endpoint, you could use a 3rd party library. Here's an example from my library, [LINQ to Twitter v3.0 Beta](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/):

```
        ulong tweetID = 210591841312190464;

        var status =
            await
            (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
             where tweet.Type == StatusType.Retweeters &&
                   tweet.ID == tweetID
             select tweet)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        if (status != null && status.User != null)
            status.Users.ForEach(
                userID => Console.WriteLine("User ID: " + userID));
```

BTW, there's also a [Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/).